# encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)

Tags: python, django

Im using Django to host my backend, user inputs their email, I check if email exists if not I generate a token and send a verification email. However when I try and use the send_email() function I get the following error:

```
encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

Here is the section of code:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            UserModel = get_user_model()
            user, user_created = UserModel.objects.get_or_create(email=email)

            if user_created:
                token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
                user_email, email_created = UserEmail.objects.get_or_create(email=email)

                if not email_created:
                    user_email.token = token
                    user_email.save()

                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                domain = current_site.domain.split(':')[0]
                print(domain)


                mail_subject = 'Activate your email'
                uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user_email.pk))
                message = render_to_string(
                    'verification_email.html',
                    {
                        'user_email': user_email,
                        'domain': domain,
                        'uid': uid,
                        'token': token,
                    },
                )
                send_mail(mail_subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [email], fail_silently=False,)
                

                return redirect('email_sent')  # Redirect to a success page
            else:
                # User with the same email already exists
                return render(request, 'email_exists.html')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I attempted to run a basic test to just send an email using the function with no luck, I then tried the same test script on a different PC with no issues, any thoughts on what environmental variables to take into account?